# keep Jframe always on focus

Tags: java, swing

My java program has multiple classes

- One Class is responsible for creating a Jframe
- Another class is responsible for writing text , which will be displayed on the jframe
- Then another class responsible for other functionalities and so on.

eg

```
new Classname.CreatedJFrame();// generate jframe
new Classname.DisplayText(); //generate text which will be displayed on jframe  
new Classname.DoSomething(); this will do something else;
```

These above functions are being looped up.

I am taking input via jframe which will detect which key was pressed via keyboard(0-9)  **However the cursor does not always stays over Jframe , I have to quickly click jframe and type the input (if delayed again i have to click the jframe area to bring pointer on focus)**

Is there any solution by which the focus can always be on the jframe and input can be provided any time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess this is happening because the control is continuously shifting among these 3 line which is reason why pointer is not always on focus over jframe

Comment: You should post a code snippet or something. It's quite unclear to understand what you mean now.